# Error with java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Hadoop MapReduce Process

Tags: java, docker, hadoop, mapreduce, hue

I've some problems making a map reduce job for process a cdv file. The problem is with the map process but I'm not sure. I'm doing..

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        final String[] arrayCsv = value.toString().split(DELIMETER);

        LOG.info("This file has " + arrayCsv.length);

        final String victimas = format(arrayCsv[19]);
        final int intValue = NumberUtils.toInt(victimas);

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayCsv.length; i++) {

            String name = getNameById(i);

            if (i > 6 && i < 20 && validBooleanStatus(name)) {

                context.write(new Text(name), new IntWritable(intValue));
            }

        }
    }
```

But when I run the map reduce job in my cluster. Well, I found this error..

```
Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 19
at com.master.tarea.Task$MaperSolution.map(Task.java:99)
at com.master.tarea.Task$MaperSolution.map(Task.java:83)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

I don't realize why map reduce cannot read my csv file but it seems like the file is not there. Please if you see some problems with the code, leave me know. Thanks so much for any help you can give me!!

**EDIT**

This is my Job Code...

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.err.println("ENTRADA ........" + args[0]);
    System.err.println("SALIDA.........." + args[1]);

    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("AccidentMapReduce required params: {input file} {output dir}");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    deleteOutputFileIfExists(args);

    final Job job = new Job(getConf());
    job.setJarByClass(Task.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    job.setMapperClass(MaperSolution.class);
    job.setReducerClass(ReducerSolution.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.

Comment: According to the error message, the illegal index is 19!

Comment: @jokster what's the actual value

Comment: The index in question is 19. It is hardcoded in code line 3.

Comment: yeah  the problem is not that. In fact, my csv file is more than 19 rows, thats the problem!! It seems like it's not getting the access to the file

Answer (score 0):

You have a constant array access at this line:

```
final String victimas = format(arrayCsv[19]);
```

The message says that the illegal index is indeed `19`. Therefore I guess that the array is smaller. So you seem to have a csv line that is too short.